# Как определить, есть ли в графе циклы отрицательного веса?

Tags: графы, c++

Граф задаётся матрицей смежности

Answer (score 1):

[Беллман—Форд](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Finding_negative_cycles) же!

Comment: @VladD, z знаю, что Беллман-Форд....но как мне вывети количество вершин, которые входят в цикл и эти вершины?

Comment: у вас же есть «таблица предшественников». идите по ней. когда зациклитесь, вот вам и отрицательный цикл.

как находить цикл, вы, надеюсь знаете (два указателя и фсё такоэ)